# While using ragas evaluate method, I am getting ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED]

Tags: python, openai-api

```
for query in questions:
    content,answer = rag_pipeline(query)
    answers.append(answer)
    contexts.append([content])

# To dict
data = {
    "question": questions,
    "answer": answers,
    "contexts": contexts,
    "ground_truths": ground_truths
}

# Convert dict to dataset
print(data)
dataset = Dataset.from_dict(data)

result = evaluate(dataset = dataset,
                    #is_async = True, 
                    metrics=[context_precision,
                            context_recall,
                            faithfulness,
                            answer_relevancy,
                            ],
)

df = result.to_pandas()
```

I am running above code to generate evaluate my rag pipeline. I have checked dataset is created with proper format which ragas is expecting. but while running evaluate I am getting below error

```
openai.APIConnectionError: Connection error.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\VI20095818\Documents\EDJ\evaluation\ragas_testing.py", line 417, in <module>
    result = evaluate(dataset = dataset,
  File "C:\Users\VI20095818\Documents\edjenv\lib\site-packages\ragas\evaluation.py", line 230, in evaluate
    raise e
  File "C:\Users\VI20095818\Documents\edjenv\lib\site-packages\ragas\evaluation.py", line 212, in evaluate
    raise ExceptionInRunner()
ragas.exceptions.ExceptionInRunner: The runner thread which was running the jobs raised an exeception. Read the traceback above to debug it. You can also pass `raise_exception=False` incase you want to show only a warning message instead.
Task was destroyed but it is pending!
```

In traceback, it is showing

```
httpx.ConnectError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1129)
```

**I have Azure openAI key which I use in my code and have set key to the same value.**

Answer (score 1):

I diged dipper and found that we can pass our own llm and embeddings to evaluate method.

```
from langchain_openai.chat_models import AzureChatOpenAI
from langchain_openai.embeddings import AzureOpenAIEmbeddings

azure_model = AzureChatOpenAI(
openai_api_version = "",
azure_endpoint = "",
azure_deployment = "",
model = "",
validate_base_url  = ""
)

azure_embeddings = AzureOpenAIEmbeddings(
openai_api_version = "",
azure_endpoint = "",
azure_deployment = "",
model = "",
validate_base_url  = ""
)

result = evaluate(dataset = dataset,
                  llm = azure_model,
                  embeddings = azure_embeddings,
                  #is_async = True, 
                  metrics=[context_precision,
                           context_recall,
                           faithfulness,
                           answer_relevancy,
                           ],
                  )
```

And it worked.